# Keyboard layout doesn't change in some applications like vscode, chrome

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, keyboard-layout

I am new in ubuntu. I use ubuntu 18.04

Every thing was fine till more than 1 month ago, I changed my keyboard layout like always by `super`+`space` keys. Whilst name of layout had been changed from `en` to `fa` (Persian) in my top task bar but it didn't change in chrome and it typed just with latin words. I tried in another applications like Firefox and visual studio code and they had this problem too. But some like my text editor or ubuntu search fields, were okay and there was no problem. I still have this problem. I've tried too much and I've read all related solutions on this website and other websites, but I couldn't solve my problem.

If there's anyone who knows how can I solve this problem, please help me! It's going to be very difficult for me to continue with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it myself :)

On the login screen where I have to enter my password, there is a tools icon. It has 2 options. For my problem, the correct option was `Ubuntu`.